# From Gogo Shell, get version of com.liferay.portal.kernel

Tags: liferay, osgi, apache-felix, liferay-7, gogo-shell

All I have is a Gogo Shell connection to a Liferay server.

From that shell, is there any way to know the version of the [com.liferay.portal.kernel](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay.portal/com.liferay.portal.kernel) package used by that server?

For instance, if I want to know the version of the [com.liferay.util.taglib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay.portal/com.liferay.util.taglib) package I would type `lb | grep Taglib | grep Util` and see that the version is `2.9.0`, but the same method does not seem to work for the kernel package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

portal-kernel.jar is still in the global classpath (lib/ext folder). Not sure you can handle it through the OSGi container.

You can check the installed version in its manifest file inside that jar.

Anyways, I guess you're asking in order to set the dependency in your developments. If that's the case, I would recomend to set the older version you can use in terms of compatibility (see a post by Nebinger talking about that: https://community.liferay.com/es/blogs/-/blogs/choosing-osgi-versions-during-development)

Your best bet is not always using the latest version for a dependency.

Comment: So this command gives the version I guess? `unzip -j $LIFERAY_HOME/tomcat/lib/ext/portal-kernel.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -d /tmp/; grep "^Bundle-Version" /tmp/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: If you are at the server, why not? Even better using zgrep or similar tools, so you dont have to unzip the jar first, leaving it there.
`zgrep "^Bundle-Version" $LIFERAY_HOME/tomcat/lib/ext/portal-kernel.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using gogo shell is not possible.

You can reach the version number calling json web service:

`λ curl http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/portal/get-build-number -u user:pwd`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
lb | grep Foundation
```

To fetch the "Liferay Foundation" Version which correspond to something like `7.0.72` for a DXP7.0 environment. I am not sure if this applies to DXP7.1 as well.

Comment: The highest ever version of com.liferay.portal.kernel is `3.61.0`, see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay.portal/com.liferay.portal.kernel

Comment: OK, sorry. The snippet will return the DXP version which is not the same as the kernel version.